# changing camera's reference point position by a keyboard event

Tags: opengl, camera, events

I would like to change the camera's reference point position using gluLookAt. I would like that it changes when I press for exemle 'a'. I tried with:

```
void VueOpenGL::Paint(wxPaintEvent&){
SetCurrent();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(65.0, 4.0/3.0, 1.0, 1000.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(100, 0.0, 0.0,
           X,   Y,  0.0, 
           0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

}

void VueOpenGL::OnKeyChar(wxKeyEvent& event)
{
   switch (event.GetKeyCode() ){
       case 97:
             X=coordinatesX_obj;
             Y=coordinatesY_obj; 
         break;
    }
 }
```

Everything is ok with the constructor of the class VueOpenGL. Despate that nothing happend when I press 'a'. Do I make something wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the values `coordinatesX_obj` and `coordinatesY_obj` from?

Comment: @Polar They are attributes of the class VueOpenGL and they can take any values.